# Issue with Apache Camel https rest api with username and password

Tags: apache-camel

I have the following piece of code, I've built for connecting to a "https" REST end point using Apache Camel. The problem is that I get 401 error if this is run.

```
from("timer:learnTimer?period=100s")
            .to("log:?level=INFO&showBody=true")
            .setHeader("currentTime", simple(currentTime))
            .setHeader(Exchange.CONTENT_TYPE,constant("application/json"))
            .setHeader(Exchange.HTTP_METHOD, constant("GET"))
            .setHeader(Exchange.HTTP_URI, simple("https://xxxxxx/api/siem/offenses?filter=status%20%3D%20%22OPEN%22%20and%20start_time%20%3E%201543647979000?&authMethod=Basic&authUsername=xxxxx&authPassword=xxxxx"))
            .to("https://xxxxxxx/api/siem/offenses?filter=status%20%3D%20%22OPEN%22%20and%20start_time%20%3E%201543647979000?&authMethod=Basic&authUsername=xxxx&authPassword=xxxx").convertBodyTo(String.class)
            .to("log:?level=INFO&showBody=true");
```

---

The error I am receiving is:

### Stacktrace

org.apache.camel.http.common.HttpOperationFailedException: HTTP operation failed invoking https://xx.xx.xx.xx/api/siem/offenses?filter=status+%3D+%22OPEN%22+and+start_time+%3E+1543647979000%3F with statusCode: 401
        at org.apache.camel.component.http.HttpProducer.populateHttpOperationFailedException(HttpProducer.java:243)
        at org.apache.camel.component.http.HttpProducer.process(HttpProducer.java:165)
        at org.apache.camel.util.AsyncProcessorConverterHelper$ProcessorToAsyncProcessorBridge.process(AsyncProcessorConverterHelper.java:61)
        at org.apache.camel.processor.SendProcessor.process(SendProcessor.java:148)
        at org.apache.camel.processor.RedeliveryErrorHandler.process(RedeliveryErrorHandler.java:548)
        at org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelInternalProcessor.java:201)
        at org.apache.camel.processor.Pipeline.process(Pipeline.java:138)
        at org.apache.camel.processor.Pipeline.process(Pipeline.java:101)
        at org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelInternalProcessor.java:201)
        at org.apache.camel.component.timer.TimerConsumer.sendTimerExchange(TimerConsumer.java:197)
        at org.apache.camel.component.timer.TimerConsumer$1.run(TimerConsumer.java:79)
        at java.util.TimerThread.mainLoop(Timer.java:555)
        at java.util.TimerThread.run(Timer.java:505)
15:16| WARN | CamelLogger.java 213 | Error processing exchange. Exchange[ID-zabbixproxy-node2-1544019394005-0-1]. Caused by: [org.apache.camel.http.common.HttpOperationFailedException - HTTP operation failed invoking https://xx.xx.xx.xx/api/siem/offenses?filter=status+%3D+%22OPEN%22+and+start_time+%3E+1543647979000%3F with statusCode: 401]
org.apache.camel.http.common.HttpOperationFailedException: HTTP operation failed invoking https://10.96.40.66/api/siem/offenses?filter=status+%3D+%22OPEN%22+and+start_time+%3E+1543647979000%3F with statusCode: 401
        at org.apache.camel.component.http.HttpProducer.populateHttpOperationFailedException(HttpProducer.java:243)
        at org.apache.camel.component.http.HttpProducer.process(HttpProducer.java:165)
        at org.apache.camel.util.AsyncProcessorConverterHelper$ProcessorToAsyncProcessorBridge.process(AsyncProcessorConverterHelper.java:61)
        at org.apache.camel.processor.SendProcessor.process(SendProcessor.java:148)

Comment: Have you confirmed that the username and password is correct? A 401 error means that the server thinks this is an unauthenticated request, which would happen with invalid credentials.

Comment: I have an equivalent Python code, where I am using the same credentials and it works fine.  I am certain that this is not a credential issue.


>>> url = 'https://xxxxxxx/api/siem/offenses?filter=status%3D%22OPEN%22%20and%20start_time%20%3E%20Replace'
>>> url_new = url.replace("Replace",str(epoch))
>>>
>>> siem_request = requests.get( url_new, auth=('xxxxx', 'xxxx'),verify=False)
>>> siem_request.status_code
200
>>>

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you should set these header before making an rest call?
un necessary request headers in IN Message may cause some issue.

```
 Exchange exchange = ExchangeBuilder.anExchange(camelContext)
                         .withHeader("").withProperty("")
                         .withPattern(ExchangePattern...)
                         .withHeader(Exchange.HTTP_METHOD, HttpMethod.GET)
                          .build();
            producer.send("the end point to rest",exchange);
```

// producer is ProducerTemaplte

In above code you can set The ExchangePattern and required Headers and property (if only needed).

Hope this helps.